# Pandas Dataframe or similar in C#.NET

Tags: c#, python, .net, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on implement the C# version of a Gurobi linear program model that was earlier built in Python. I have a number of CSV files from which I was importing the data and creating pandas dataframes, and I was fetching columns from those dataframes to create variables that I was using in my Linear Program. The python code for creating the variables using dataframes is as follows:

```
dataPath = "C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/LinearProgramming/TestData"
routeData = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(os.path.join(dataPath, "DirectLink.csv"), index_col=None)
#Creating 3 Python-dictionaries from Python Multi-Dict using column names and keeping RouteID as the key
routeID, transportCost, routeType = multidict({x[0]:[x[1],x[2]] for x in routeData[['RouteID', 'TransportCost','RouteType']].values})
```

Example: If the csv structure is as follows:

```
RouteID  RouteEfficiency  TransportCost  RouteType
  1           0.8              2.00          F
  2           0.9              5.00          D
  3           0.7              6.00          R
  4           0.6              3.00          T
```

The 3 variables should be:
RouteID: 1 2 3 4

TransportCost:

```
1:2.00
2:5.00
3:6.00
4:3.00
```

RouteType:

```
1:F
2:D
3:R
4:T
```

Now, I want to create a C# version of the above code that does the same task, but I learnt that C# doesn't support dataframes. I tried looking for a few alternatives, but am unable to find anything. Please help me with this.

Comment: There's a discussion about adding better dataframe support to C# on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26845. It would be great to get more voices behind it

Comment: What is the difference between a DataFrame and a DataTable?  Couldn't a library of DataTable methods that mirror the pandas DataFrame methods be created?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Deedle` is a .Net library that handles DataFrames.

http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/index.html

Answer (score 24):

New kid on the block

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-dataframe/

Announced today, still in preview, Microsoft's own take on a DataFrame :)

Comment: The package hasn't been updated since May, 2020, and the specified source repo, https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab, has been archived.

Comment: Looks like it lives on here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML/
Source for dataframe:
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/DataFrame.cs

Comment: @eltommo You're right. They are going to release it. There are many issue associated with that part. [Someone has already asked how it will be released.](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5716)

Answer (score 5):

I was after a .NET representation of the Python Pandas library, and I came across this C# port: https://github.com/SciSharp/Pandas.NET. As of 21st March 2022, the last update was 2 months ago. The site has 5 contributers, 36 people watching, and 51 forks.
This port includes the Pandas DataFrames structure and methods.

Answer (score 2):

ML.net 2.0 was released on Nov 10, 2022 and here is the blog post reference to DataFrame https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ml-net-2-0/#dataframe

DataFrame is under the Microsoft.Data.Analysis nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Analysis/ and the source code is here https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/tree/main/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis

The ML.net docs are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/machine-learning/