# How to parse compound logic expression string in C#?

Tags: python, c#, pandas, parsing, expression

We have a data table in C# whose column header names are volatile.

```
----------------------
| Foo  |  Bar  | ... |
----------------------
```

We need provide a `TextBox` to users and have them input the search criteria and we'll query or filter out the data rows accordingly.  In `Python Pandas`, it's very easy, the user would input `Foo == 1 and Bar == True` and we'll be able to do query like this: `dataframe.query('Foo == 1 and Bar == True')`.

Now we want to use the same syntax but in `C#`.  From what I researched, `C# Expression` is the way to go.  I have no problem to build expression trees for simple logic such as `Foo == 1` (let's call such expression an atom).

My question is how to parse a compound logic expression and break it down to many atoms?  The compound logic expression will use `C-like` logic operators, for example `(Foo > 0 && Foo < 20) || Bar == True && .. || ...`.  Users might throw as many parenthesis as they want.  They might also forget to close a parenthesis and I need detect such error.

Comment: Is it a requirement to support python pandas syntax? You can directly look for [alternatives](https://www.google.com/search?q=panda+python+c%23). You are probably mixing expressions with [DataColumn expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression), where you can supply user entered text directly, but it probably uses another syntax, not like pandas.

Comment: Are you sure you really wan't to implement such an expression parser only because you want to stick to the same syntax? It's certainly possible, but it might be simpler [to look for libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065731/pandas-dataframe-or-similar-in-c-net).

Comment: As a user, I'd also consider a _TextBox_ extremely bad UX. If a column is freetext, I want to filter free text, if it is ints, I want to filter ints, if it is Dates, I'll probably want to filter Dates or Date-Ranges ... and so on.

Comment: Thanks for all comments so far.  All data cells are of type string and it is a requirement to use TextBox to input query strings.  The reason we use TextBox is that each query string is saved as a rule and users can go back and click any previous rule and the data rows are then filtered out accordingly.

Comment: Just because the fields are strings doesn't mean you have to use a string expression to filter. In any case ADO.NET DataTable isn't a Pandas DataFrame and doesn't use the same syntax. The [DataTable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-8.0) method's expressions are similar to SQL. The common way to filter and sort though is to [use a DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/sorting-and-filtering-data). Both DataTable and DataView can be bound to grid controls